# Best way to store multiple checkboxes so that I can easily query them later

Tags: php, mysql, multi-select

Let's say I have a client who is looking for an object with specific area.
So I have multiple checkboxes from which he can check the ones he wants.

```
<input type="checkbox" name="area[]" value="10" /> 10
<input type="checkbox" name="area[]" value="20" /> 20
<input type="checkbox" name="area[]" value="30" /> 30
<input type="checkbox" name="area[]" value="40" /> 40
<input type="checkbox" name="area[]" value="50" /> 50
```

This is probably not the best way to store the area values as I want to easly query for rows which meet my criteria. Would it be better to put it this way:

```
 <input type="checkbox" name="area_10" value="true" /> 10
 <input type="checkbox" name="area_20" value="true" /> 20
 <input type="checkbox" name="area_30" value="true" /> 30
 <input type="checkbox" name="area_40" value="true" /> 40
 <input type="checkbox" name="area_50" value="true" /> 50
```

So that I have separate columns in a database table (area_10, area_20, area_30 etc.). If this is the optimal solution, then what would the sql query look to retrieve rows which have checked the area between 10 and 40?

Answer (score 0):

with many-to-one data, you need to use relational data storage.  you need an "area" table where you store the areas that belong to the object.  each row has the area number and the object foreign id.  so you can then write a join that will pull the many to one data and make it easy to store, understand, and query.

and example of a join that would pull the areas that were selected and stored for object # 1972:

```
select
  o.id, o.name, group_concat(a.area) areas
from
  objects o left join
  area a on o.id = a.object_id
where
  o.id = 1972;
```

**EDIT**
an example of how to select all objects which contain areas between 30 and 60

```
select
  o.id, o.name, group_concat(a.area) areas
from
  objects o left join
  area a on o.id = a.object_id
where
  a.area between '30' and '60';
```

and additionally area equal to 90

```
select
  o.id, o.name, group_concat(a.area) areas
from
  objects o left join
  area a on o.id = a.object_id
where
  a.area = '90';
```

Comment: I understand, thank you. Would you please give me an example of how to select all objects which contain areas between 30 and 60, and additionally area equal to 90?

Comment: @patrickferry it is as you have requested (in my updated answer).

Answer (score 0):

There's not enough information to give the optimal solution, but basically if all that is required is to find all the objects with certain areas corresponding to the selected values in the client then all that is needed on the server side is a table (say objects_table) with two columns i.e the object (or it's id) and it's area.

The server side receives from the client side the list of values of the checkboxes that were selected (say 10, 20, 40) and accordingly builds and runs a simple query (don't forget to escape values to avoid possible injection),

```
SELECT id, area FROM objects_table WHERE area IN (10, 20, 40)
```

Since I doubt areas will have nice discrete values in real life, I'm assuming this is either an educational example or I've misunderstood the question...